# QGraphicsItem::shape() does not match click hit

Tags: qt, qt5

I'm having some issues with Qt (5.6).

I'm using a **QGraphicsItemGroup** to represent an arc (Bezier curve, left to right then rotated) on a **QGraphicsScene**.
I want this arc to be selectable by user when clicking on it, or near it. The idea is to make the arc itself clickable, as well as a small strip around the arc.

To to do, I use **QGraphicsItem::shape()** to return a shape corresponding to the area I want to be clickable.

## Context

The code to generate the shape is as follows, with *arrowPath* being the arc path itself (explanations below):

```
QPainterPath arrowPath = ((QGraphicsPathItem*)this->arrowBody)->path();

path.moveTo(0, this->middleBarLength/2);
path.lineTo(0, -this->middleBarLength/2);

arrowPath.translate(0, -this->middleBarLength/2);
path.connectPath(arrowPath);

path.lineTo(arrowPath.boundingRect().width(), this->middleBarLength/2);

arrowPath.translate(0, this->middleBarLength);
arrowPath = arrowPath.toReversed();
path.connectPath(arrowPath);

path.closeSubpath();

QTransform t;
t.rotate(-sceneAngle);
this->boundingShape = t.map(path);
```

This codes does the following:

- Draw a vertical line (bottom up) with size *middleBarLength* (strip width) vertically centered on the arc,
- Translate the arc path to latest position and link it,
- Draw another vertical line (top down),
- Reverse the arc path, translate it to the latest position and link it,
- Close the path,
- Rotate the shape to match the arc rotation.

***EDIT BEGIN***

As per suggested by Kuba Ober, I changed the above code to the following, which is much more simple:

```
QPainterPath arrowPath = ((QGraphicsPathItem*)this->arrowBody)->path();

QPen pen(QBrush(Qt::SolidPattern), this->middleBarLength/2);
QPainterPathStroker stroker(pen);

path = stroker.createStroke(arrowPath);

QTransform t;
t.rotate(-sceneAngle);
this->boundingShape = t.map(path);
```

But this doesn't solve the issue itself...

***EDIT END***

The **shape()** function then just returns the *boundingShape* object, which is updated on any change on the arc.

The *boundingShape* object is also used for another purpose: to display a dotted box indicating the arc is selected (overriding the default selection box). This codes produces a correct shape when I display the selection box.

## Issue

The problem occurs as follows: while the shape seems to be observed for the outer part (clicking outside the shape on the convex side does not select it, unlike a **boundingRect()** ), it is not OK for the inner shape: clicking outside the shape, on the concave side, in a place that is between two points of the arc DOES select it. I'm not sure I'm very clear on my explanations, I hope you see what I mean.

Problem is I can have various arcs, with different radius of curvature, but with the same origin/target. All being on the same Z stacking order, the incorrect arc can be selected. I can't define a different Z position without major modification to my code.

I tried working around manually, and managed to do so by adding a specific check on click:

```
mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* ev)
{
    if ( ! this->boundingShape.contains(ev->pos()) )
        ev->ignore();
}
```

But I don't understand why I have to do this, and this could potentially be harmful because I can't implement the mouse release, double click and move function without breaking this behavior. Moreover, by adding this code, it works on mouse release and not mouse down.

So if anyone has a hint on what's happening, I would be very thankful.

## Additional information

If required, full code for the class is available here [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/states/code/ci/master/tree/ui/scene/fsm/fsmgraphictransition.cpp) in function *rebuildBoundingShape()* (line 341). This is the *else* of the *else* (line 401).

Comment: I've looked at the code and the approach seems superbly complex. All you want is one path that is the visible path drawn for the item. You then use a `QPainterPathStroker` to stroke it with a thick pen to get an outline that is easier to click: this is even [documented](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#shape). This should be done at the level of items within the group, you shouldn't be overriding the group's methods. Once the individual items react sanely, the group will simply follow their behavior: you click on any item and it's as if you clicked on the group.

Comment: TL;DR: If you're overriding `shape()` of `QGraphicsItemGroup`, you're probably doing something else wrong.

Comment: @Kuba Ober: I don't want the object to be bolder. I want it to remain thin, but I want a click near it to select it. Moreover, I don't want individual objects from the group to be selectable: I want the grouped object to be selectable. All elements of the group remain in the strip around the arc. I don't understand is why I shouldn't override the group's shape()? The group IS my base object...

Comment: You don't want the object to be bolder, but you want its **shape** to be so :) The shape is used for mouse hit detection, collision detection, etc. The group already works the way you want: you select any one of the grouped objects, and the whole group gets selected. You shouldn't override the group's shape because you don't have to. It's supposed to be easy and you're making it very complicated instead. Try it out on trivial examples to understand what's going on.

Comment: OK, let's see if I understand what you mean: I create a stroke for the arc only (not the other objects of the group), making it looking bolder to the click hit. Then the group makes the whole clickable area the union of the independent objects shapes.
How does the selection shape (dotted outline) react then? Does it follow the stroke? I first created the shape object to provide this selection shape, then I chose to use it for click hit too...
If a stroke replaces both, I'll use it. I'll look into it.
By the way, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @KubaOber Ok, I tried replacing my shape generation with the following:
`QPen pen(QBrush(Qt::SolidPattern), 40);
unique_ptr<QPainterPathStroker> stroker(new QPainterPathStroker(pen));
path = stroker->createStroke(arrowPath);`
It works as you say, and is pretty simple to use but... I still have the same issue!